# Options Enum Equivalent in Swift

Tags: objective-c, swift

Take for these two methods in the `NSCalander` class:

```
component(unit: NSCalanderUnit, fromDate: NSDate) -> Int
components(unitFlags: NSCalanderUnit, fromDate: NSDate) -> NSDateComponents
```

In the first method we call it with a single **NSCalanderUnit**:

```
someCalander.component(unit: .Minute, fromDate: NSDate())
```

In the second method the type signature suggests we give it a single **NSCalanderUnit** but in reality to provide more than one unit we would need to call the method like so:

```
components(unitFlags: [.Hour, .Day], fromDate: NSDate)
```

Now, I understand the reason for it saying it requires just an **NSCalanderUnit** as opposed to **[NSCalanderUnit]** is that the cocoa framework was written in Objective-C and subsequently bridges the code to swift. In Objective-C the `NSCalanderUnit` is a an NS_Option "enum" per say. In which we use a bitmask to combine multiple flags (or "options") we use the bitwise operator ***|***.

So my question:

**Why do we call it in square brackets instead of calling it like so:**

```
components(unitFlags: .Hour | .Day, fromDate: NSDate)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is known as an option set, bridged automatically from an Objective C `NS_OPTION`. They are effectively a more type-safe way of handling an enum type in which multiple options can be selected. In Swift, these values are not treated like bit masks (as in Objective C and hence why the `|` operator is not valid here) but rather as distinct values of an enum. An option set effectively acts like a Set of that enum, providing a type safe bridge with equivalent functionality.

Apple specifies the details of their implementation here:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/InteractingWithCAPIs.html

Answer (score 1):

> Why do we call it with an array literal when it is not considered an array

It's not an array. It's more like a set. In point of fact, it's an Option Set.

Comment: See my book if you can't be bothered to read Apple's documentation: http://www.apeth.com/swiftBook/ch04.html#SECoptionsSets

Answer (score 1):

This is [`OptionSetType`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/watchos/documentation/Swift/Reference/Swift_OptionSetType_Protocol/index.html). It's what you get when you import an NS_`OPTIONS` enum from C, and you can create your own in Swift using the style shown on the linked docs page:

```
struct PackagingOptions : OptionSetType {
    let rawValue: Int
    init(rawValue: Int) { self.rawValue = rawValue }

    static let Box = PackagingOptions(rawValue: 1)
    static let Carton = PackagingOptions(rawValue: 2)
    static let Bag = PackagingOptions(rawValue: 4)
    static let Satchel = PackagingOptions(rawValue: 8)
    static let BoxOrBag: PackagingOptions = [Box, Bag]
    static let BoxOrCartonOrBag: PackagingOptions = [Box, Carton, Bag]
}
```

Why is it like this? Types like this, as they're used in API, are conceptually *sets*: groupings of one or more unique values. That we create them as bitfields in C is merely an implementation detail. Getting the bitwise operations right for all but the most basic set constructions and queries is easy to get wrong, and even when it's correct, it's verbose and doesn't read clearly — one has to intuit that a bunch of ORs and ANDs means "if it's any of values A, B, or D but not C or E".

By contrast, when you create or import an `OptionSetType`, you get automatic implementations of [all the set operations](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/watchos/documentation/Swift/Reference/Swift_SetAlgebraType_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/swift/intf/s:Ps14SetAlgebraType), like `contains` and `intersect` and `isEmpty`.  And you can use set/array-style literal to construct values, which more accurately says "I want the `Hour` and `Day` components" instead of "I want some integer value that's the bitwise OR of whatever `Hour` and `Day` are".